# Terminating Activity Diagram on User side

Tags: activity-diagram

Currently I am creating an activity diagram for adding a new element.
The last step is that the application shows a list with all elements including the new one. But from what I've learned the diagram has to terminate on user side, therefore I am searching for a good last step.

Things which came in my mind so far (on user side):

- Sees new element on screen
- Sees all element including the new one (maybe way too long)
- Sees a list of all elements

This is my diagram so far, feel free to improve it!
[image]

Comment: "from what I've learned the diagram has to terminate on user side" Can you reference a source?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity diagram gives the reader no clue about the usecase that you are describing. It is very generic from a business perspective and may be applicable for any kind of entity.

Once you embed the handling of such entity in a concrete business use case, you'll find it easy to reference a "next step" where such newly created entity is used. For example, say your new element is an address. Then that address would be used in a context. Such as: Start navigating to that address. And that could be described in another diagram.

If you want to keep it that abstract, you could introduce some abstract action such as "verify results" or "proceed to next step" which at least implies that the newly entered information will be used later in some way or another (= benefits someone).